# Fastlane : [altool] Error: Unable to upload archive. Failed to get authorization for username and password

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect, fastlane, ipa, fastlane-pilot

I try to upload my flutter ipa to the AppStore with fastlane using pilot with the following command:

```
bundle exec fastlane pilot upload --ipa ../build/ios/ipa/project.ipa
```

When I run this command I face the following error

I have a .p8 in the private_keys folder

It seems that pilot can log me with my apple ID but just after it throws me that it failed to get authorization.

After it failed, when I go to TestFlight I can see my new version available but with the old version name (e.g. 1.0.0 instead of 1.0.1)

```
[monsieur_x | ~/project/ios ]$ bundle exec fastlane pilot upload --ipa ../build/ios/ipa/project.ipa
[✔]  
[17:54:31]: Login to App Store Connect (apple_id@gmail.com)
[17:54:33]: Login successful
[17:54:35]: Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 1544671867)...
[17:54:39]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[17:54:39]: This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
[17:54:41]: [altool] 2022-10-26 17:54:41.294 *** Error: Unable to upload archive. Failed to get authorization for username 'apple_id@gmail.com' and password. (

[17:54:41]: [altool]     "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=0 \"Status code: 0\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Status code: 0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The auth server returned a bad status code.}"

[17:54:41]: [altool] ) (-1011)

[17:54:41]: [altool]  {

[17:54:41]: [altool]     NSLocalizedDescription = "Unable to upload archive.";

[17:54:41]: [altool]     NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Failed to get authorization for username 'apple_id@gmail.com' and password. (\n    \"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=0 \\\"Status code: 0\\\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Status code: 0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The auth server returned a bad status code.}\"\n)";

[17:54:41]: [altool] }

[17:54:41]: Application Loader output above ^
[17:54:41]: Error uploading '/var/folders/gr/z1j06nhs2sd38gwv4_l51rj40000gn/T/7d36fd34-357d-4c08-aa9d-7db6ed3a8b82.ipa'.
[17:54:41]: Unable to upload archive. Failed to get authorization for username 'apple_id@gmail.com' and password. (
[17:54:41]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
[17:54:41]: Could not download/upload from App Store Connect!

[!] Error uploading ipa file: 
 [Application Loader Error Output]: Error uploading '/var/folders/gr/z1j06nhs2sd38gwv4_l51rj40000gn/T/7d36fd34-357d-4c08-aa9d-7db6ed3a8b82.ipa'.
[Application Loader Error Output]: Unable to upload archive. Failed to get authorization for username 'apple_id@gmail.com' and password. (
[Application Loader Error Output]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
```

Here is my fastlane env if you need:

```
<details><summary> fastlane environment </summary>

### Stack

| Key                         | Value                                                          |
| --------------------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------- |
| OS                          | 12.6                                                           |
| Ruby                        | 2.6.8                                                          |
| Bundler?                    | false                                                          |
| Git                         | git version 2.38.0                                             |
| Installation Source         | /usr/local/bin/fastlane                                        |
| Host                        | macOS 12.6 (21G115)                                            |
| Ruby Lib Dir                | /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib |
| OpenSSL Version             | LibreSSL 2.8.3                                                 |
| Is contained                | false                                                          |
| Is homebrew                 | false                                                          |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false                                                          |
| Xcode Path                  | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/                    |
| Xcode Version               | 14.0.1                                                         |
| Swift Version               | 5.7                                                            |


### System Locale

| Error                       |
| --------------------------- |
| No Locale with UTF8 found  |


### fastlane files:

<details><summary>`./fastlane/Fastfile`</summary>
```

```rb
# This file contains the fastlane.tools configuration
# You can find the documentation at https://docs.fastlane.tools
#
# For a list of all available actions, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
#
# For a list of all available plugins, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/available-plugins
#

# Uncomment the line if you want fastlane to automatically update itself
# update_fastlane

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "Runner.xcodeproj")
    build_app(workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace", scheme: "Runner")
    upload_to_testflight
  end
end
```

`./fastlane/Appfile`

```rb
app_identifier("com.balanz") # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id("contact@balanz.fr") # Your Apple Developer Portal username

itc_team_id("122453945") # App Store Connect Team ID
team_id("T3P8853DAC") # Developer Portal Team ID

# For more information about the Appfile, see:
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#appfile
```

#### fastlane gems

| Gem | Version | Update-Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fastlane | 2.210.1 | ✅ Up-To-Date |

#### Loaded fastlane plugins:

**No plugins Loaded**

**Loaded gems**

| Gem | Version |
| --- | --- |
| did_you_mean | 1.3.0 |
| atomos | 0.1.3 |
| colored2 | 3.1.2 |
| nanaimo | 0.3.0 |
| rexml | 3.2.5 |
| xcodeproj | 1.21.0 |
| rouge | 2.0.7 |
| xcpretty | 0.3.0 |
| terminal-notifier | 2.0.0 |
| unicode-display_width | 1.8.0 |
| terminal-table | 1.8.0 |
| plist | 3.6.0 |
| public_suffix | 4.0.6 |
| addressable | 2.8.0 |
| multipart-post | 2.0.0 |
| word_wrap | 1.0.0 |
| optparse | 0.1.1 |
| tty-screen | 0.8.1 |
| tty-cursor | 0.7.1 |
| tty-spinner | 0.9.3 |
| artifactory | 3.0.15 |
| babosa | 1.0.4 |
| colored | 1.2 |
| highline | 2.0.3 |
| commander | 4.6.0 |
| excon | 0.92.2 |
| faraday-em_http | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-em_synchrony | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-excon | 1.1.0 |
| faraday-httpclient | 1.0.1 |
| faraday-multipart | 1.0.3 |
| faraday-net_http | 1.0.1 |
| faraday-net_http_persistent | 1.2.0 |
| faraday-patron | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-rack | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-retry | 1.0.3 |
| ruby2_keywords | 0.0.5 |
| faraday | 1.10.0 |
| unf_ext | 0.0.8.1 |
| unf | 0.1.4 |
| domain_name | 0.5.20190701 |
| http-cookie | 1.0.4 |
| faraday-cookie_jar | 0.0.7 |
| faraday_middleware | 1.2.0 |
| fastimage | 2.2.6 |
| gh_inspector | 1.1.3 |
| mini_magick | 4.11.0 |
| naturally | 2.2.1 |
| rubyzip | 2.3.2 |
| security | 0.1.3 |
| xcpretty-travis-formatter | 1.0.1 |
| dotenv | 2.7.6 |
| bundler | 2.3.10 |
| simctl | 1.6.8 |
| jwt | 2.3.0 |
| uber | 0.1.0 |
| declarative | 0.0.20 |
| trailblazer-option | 0.1.2 |
| representable | 3.1.1 |
| retriable | 3.1.2 |
| mini_mime | 1.1.2 |
| memoist | 0.16.2 |
| multi_json | 1.15.0 |
| os | 1.1.4 |
| signet | 0.16.1 |
| googleauth | 1.1.2 |
| httpclient | 2.8.3 |
| google-apis-core | 0.4.2 |
| google-apis-playcustomapp_v1 | 0.7.0 |
| google-apis-androidpublisher_v3 | 0.17.0 |
| google-cloud-env | 1.6.0 |
| google-cloud-errors | 1.2.0 |
| google-cloud-core | 1.6.0 |
| google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 | 0.10.0 |
| google-apis-storage_v1 | 0.11.0 |
| digest-crc | 0.6.4 |
| google-cloud-storage | 1.36.1 |
| emoji_regex | 3.2.3 |
| jmespath | 1.6.1 |
| aws-partitions | 1.572.0 |
| aws-eventstream | 1.2.0 |
| aws-sigv4 | 1.4.0 |
| aws-sdk-core | 3.130.0 |
| aws-sdk-kms | 1.55.0 |
| aws-sdk-s3 | 1.113.0 |
| CFPropertyList | 3.0.5 |
| claide | 1.1.0 |
| json | 2.6.1 |
| webrick | 1.7.0 |
| rake | 13.0.6 |
| forwardable | 1.2.0 |
| logger | 1.3.0 |
| date | 2.0.0 |
| stringio | 0.0.2 |
| ipaddr | 1.2.2 |
| openssl | 2.1.2 |
| zlib | 1.0.0 |
| mutex_m | 0.1.0 |
| ostruct | 0.1.0 |
| strscan | 1.0.0 |
| io-console | 0.4.7 |
| fileutils | 1.1.0 |
| etc | 1.0.1 |
| libxml-ruby | 3.2.1 |
| psych | 3.1.0 |

*generated on:* **2022-10-27**

Does someone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Having the same problem :/

Comment: How you solved it ?

Comment: @ankitjaiswal
the answer is useful, create a `.env.default` file, please.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Hello I was struggling with this issue for many days.

**Solution**

Step 1

Go to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage login in and go to App-Specific Passwords, after generate a new App Specific Password copy it.

Step2

Inside fastlane folder create a new file .env.default and add the two properties .

```
FASTLANE_USER=<Apple USER ID>
FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD=<App-Specific Password>
```

Use an app-specific password to sign in to an app or service not provided by Apple such as fastlane.

**------------------------------Other options--------------------------------**

You have different options not only using .env file.

**1- In your Fastfile**

```
FASTLANE_USER=<Apple USER ID>
FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD=<App-Specific Password>

lane :beta do
  crashlytics
end
```

**2- Bash Profile**

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

insert your properties

```
FASTLANE_USER=<Apple USER ID>
FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD=<App-SpecificPassword>
```

CTRL + X -  save changes.
reopen your terminal

Please in check the link for more details about.
https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/keys/

Comment: Thanks, I ran into this now, but I would just add, that one should not commit that file to version control, or alternatively simply add that to your machine env via one of the `rc` files.

Comment: @RemeJuan Agree 100%

Comment: @alexanderferreras How to Add .env.default file, as when I was trying to add file name with . its not allowing to have file name start with "." and throwing error. Please guide.

Comment: @PareshKarnawat go to fastlane folder using your terminal and run "touch env.default" . That is all and after that you will enable to edit it

Comment: @alexanderferreras Will it work with fastlane spaceauth instead of app-specific password ?

Comment: @ankitjaiswal I haven't tested it but, maybe could be, If you tried it please let me know.

Comment: @alexanderferreras I tried with FASTLANE_SESSION, fastlane match worked but upload_to_testflight function throws error to provide FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD. In my use case I have 200+ applications won't be possible to set specific password.

Comment: @ankitjaiswal But if the applications below to the same user account you can use only one specified password

Comment: I would prefer not to save my AppleID password in plain text on my computer. In fact, I found that I only needed to add `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD` to my .zprofile.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't need this until today, but this was helpful. One note is that Fastlane will read from the .env, I think, not the .env.defalt. So the .env should contain `FASTLANE_USER` and `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my time